# sql.NullString || sql.NullInt64 convert to normal format json null?

Tags: go

Often happens in relational database, that when selecting records from the database, the field is returned.
Go does not process strings and numbers as nil, in this case there is an auxiliary type of sql.Null {type}
But if you return data in json format, then use of this type becomes unnecessary since, in javascript, there is null.

Now I sql.NullString convert to manual. Also there is a variant in sql itself to return, not null, and an empty line (if it is a line),
but for some reasons in the future it will be difficult to debug.

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, why not just scan into a `*string` or `*int`. Those types can be marshaled by `encoding/json`.

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/piotrkowalczuk/ntypes this package provides types like `sql.NullString` that implements also few other interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little confusing but I think I understand what you are asking.  Inspired by another post that I can no longer find, I wrote wrappers around the sql.Null types to encode JSON as primitive types.  See example below:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
)

type JsonNullInt64 struct {
    sql.NullInt64
}

type JsonNullFloat64 struct {
    sql.NullFloat64
}

type JsonNullString struct {
    sql.NullString
}

type JsonNullBool struct {
    sql.NullBool
}

func (v *JsonNullBool) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if v.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(v.Bool)
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(nil)
    }
}

func (v *JsonNullBool) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var b *bool
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &b); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if b != nil {
        v.Valid = true
        v.Bool = *b
    } else {
        v.Valid = false
    }

    return nil
}

func (v *JsonNullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if v.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(v.String)
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(nil)
    }
}

func (v *JsonNullString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var str *string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &str); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if str != nil {
        v.Valid = true
        v.String = *str
    } else {
        v.Valid = false
    }

    return nil
}

func (v JsonNullFloat64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if v.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(v.Float64)
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(0)
    }
}

func (v *JsonNullFloat64) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Unmarshalling into a pointer will let us detect null

    var x *float64
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &x)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if x != nil {
        v.Valid = true
        v.Float64 = *x
    } else {
        v.Valid = false
    }
    return nil
}

func (v JsonNullInt64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if v.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(v.Int64)
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(0)
    }
}

func (v JsonNullInt64) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Unmarshalling into a pointer will let us detect null
    var x *int64
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &x); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if x != nil {
        v.Valid = true
        v.Int64 = *x
    } else {
        v.Valid = false
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I do not know much about English yet, but I will soon learn.

Comment: Then what are you talking about here: https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/how-i-handled-null-possible-values-from-database-rows-in-golang-521fb0ee267

Comment: Yes, that looks like a similar implementation

Comment: What is the best way to parse a variable of your type JsonNullInt64 into an int?